# Android performFiltering in AutocompleteTextView filters null when below threshold

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

The setup:

- I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` with a custom ArrayAdapter and a Filter bound to it.
- I have set my autocomplete threshold to 3 from the XML using `completionThreshold` attribute.

The funny thing is that, every time the **constraint length is less than the threshold value**, Android calls `performFiltering` method with a **null constraint**.

This is indeed as implemented in `AutoCompleteTextView` (line 789):
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#783

Can someone give an explanation on such behaviour?

Comment: read the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#performFiltering(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Thanks, though they don't define what "original data" is.
Do you mind posting this as an answer?

Comment: yes, for ACTV, "original data" makes little sense but when filtering std ListViews it makes more sense

Comment: so for ACTV when constraint is null just return an empty set